# How to set profile config based on test resource port in quarkus test

Tags: testing, quarkus

I have a TestResource that starts up a testcontainer instance on a free random port.

I would then like to make my RestClient instances point to the port chosen so that they work together.

I have tried the following options:

- Set a test profile that sets the property for the url based on the port. In this case, the profile was read before the container was started and as such I have no information at hand.
- before each test, reflectively inject into an `@Inject` instance of the service I have using the restclient of choice. In this case it seems that the RestClient is created in the component after the `@BeforeEach` and so my reflectively created instance gets wiped clean.

Is there a way to make this work currently?

Eg:

Client:

```
@RegisterRestClient(configKey = "cuorium.myclient.baseUrl")
public interface MyExtApiClient {
  
}
```

In `application.yml` I then would set `cuorium.myclient.baseUrl/mp-rest/url` but I want that field to be settable based on the testcontainer port.

Comment: What is the "name" (i.e. config-key) of your rest client? Better yet, what do your REST Client interface and `application.properties` look like?

Comment: added details to question

Comment: Great thanks. Can you also add some code that illustrate what you've already tried?